# Why are medical professionals called Doctors?

Tags: etymology, history

Searching online for the origin of **Doctor** being used for medical professionals, the often repeated facts are:

1. The word comes for the Latin *to teach*
2. At some point medical professionals started to be called Doctor

https://www.merriam-webster.com/wordplay/the-history-of-doctor

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_(title)

Is it possible to find out why exactly this happened and where?

Did it happen first in English because of similar words (e.g. the verb *to doctor*)?

Comment: Definitely not - the verb comes from the noun.

Comment: Definitely goes back at least to the 1300's, with Chaucer's "Doctour of Physik". Physik is medicine (c.f. "physician"), so Chaucer is literally describing him as an "MD".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a usage which was gradually adopted during Middle Ages as [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/doctor#:%7E:text=doctor%20(v.),Related%3A%20Doctored%3B%20doctoring.) explains:

- The sense of "medical professional, person duly licensed to practice medicine" (replacing native [leech (n.2))](https://www.etymonline.com/word/leech#etymonline_v_6646) grew gradually out of this from c. 1400, though this use of the word was not common until late 16c. The transitional stage is exemplified in Chaucer's Doctor of phesike (Latin physica came to be used extensively in Medieval Latin for medicina).
- *That no man ... practyse in Fisyk ... but he be Bacheler or Doctour of Fisyk, havynge Lettres testimonyalx sufficeantz of on of those degrees of the Universite. [Rolls of Parliament, 1421]*

Comment: What are the *x* and *z* at the ends of the words in the phrase "havynge Lettres testimonyalx sufficeantz"?

Comment: This explains **when** the shift occurred, but not **why** it occurred, which was the most interesting part of the question. How did we get from teaching (in general, including on topics that have nothing to do with medicine) to practising medicine (which need not include teaching)?

Comment: @jsw29 the linked entry suggests that the word meant "learned, skilled in a learned profession" from which it was applied to medical professionals.